# dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/SceneKit

Tags: xcode, ios8, scenekit

I want to create a game on Xcode 6.0 using SceneKit, but when I run the  application it crashes on the device and prints this error on the console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/SceneKit
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/92F93C11-1A2E-4A5B-8BC1-0243E7E67151/GameApp.app/GameApp
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: I assume the device was running ios8?

Comment: my device os is ios 7.0.6 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so it looks like the issue is that the device is running iOS 7 and you need iOS 8 in order to use SceneKit.  Update the device and it should work as advertised.

Comment: Checking the app on ios8, it was run without any error. Thanks

Comment: You can change the framework 'required' property to 'optional' to bypass the compiler error for older iOS environments (in this case, iOS 7 vs 8).

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Hello, you could post your comment as an answer, because it is an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: @bluish Avoiding the compiler error (actually runtime linker error) is one thing, but how do you actually code around the missing framework?